# What is the network address and subnet mask of this hidden subnet?

Tags: subnet

I can figure out the subnet mask but have no idea how to determine the IP address. Can someone explain to me please?

[image]

Comment: This is a homework assignment, isn't it?

Comment: it's not. this question is taken off of subnettingpractice.com. I am trying to learn subnetting. The answer is 192.168.1.0/25 but I want to know how to reach that solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, its 192.168.1.0/25.

Two /25s make a /24.

- 192.168.0.0/25 + 192.168.0.128/25 = 192.168.0.0/24

192.168.1.0/24 is divided like so:

- 192.168.1.0/25 (which is 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.127, 128 addresses, 126 usable)
- 192.168.1.128/26 (which is 192.168.1.128 - 192.168.1.191, 64 addresses, 62 usable)
- 192.168.1.192/30 (which is 192.168.1.192 - 192.168.1.195, 4 addresses, 2 usable)

Make sense?

Comment: yes I know that's the answer but want it explained in more detailed on why that's the network address. One example will help me figure other questions like these.

Comment: its the network address because its the only space big enough in the given parent subnet (192.168.0.0/23) to contain 68 hosts after all the other subnets are allocated.